# Primefaces extensions ckeditor missing spellchecker and scayt icon

Tags: ckeditor, primefaces-extensions

The spellchecker and scayt icons are missing on the pe:ckeditor toolbar:

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
<pe:ckEditor id="editor" value="#{editorController.content}" toolbar="[['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt']]">
  <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{editorController.saveListener}" update="growl" />
</pe:ckEditor>
```

Both are also missing in the Primefaces Extensions Showcase for Ckeditor Custom Toolbar: 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/customToolbar.jsf

Have searched extensively and even updated pe:ckeditor.

Using Primefaces 5.1, Primefaces Extensions 3.0, JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the website, and it's using a custom, developer build of CKEditor

```
console.log( CKEDITOR.version );
"4.4.4 DEV"
```

which contains neither [SCAYT](http://ckeditor.com/addon/scayt) nor [SpellChecker](http://ckeditor.com/addon/wsc) plugins

```
console.log( CKEDITOR.plugins.registered.scayt );
undefined
```

so it's no surprise your toolbar buttons don't appear. You can [generate a custom build of CKEditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins-section-online-builder-installation) or [install plugins manually](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins-section-manual-installation). It's all up to you though it may be limited by the framework, which I'm not familiar with. But I believe it requires no special skills to modify it.

Comment: I was hoping the Primefaces Extensions ckeditor would already have these plugins since their showcase lists them so I would not have to install the plugins manually. They had them in a previous version.